# Efficient Loop to Avoid Multiple Garbage Collect Calls for Android

Tags: java, android, for-loop, garbage-collection

I have an Android app that allows the user to record data (such as accelerometer, latitude, longitude, etc.).  There are a total of 9 of these fields, and the user can record for up to 10 minutes (3000 records per field).  Therefore, a total of 27,000 data points can be collected. The user can also take pictures and videos to upload the SD Card as well.

When the user is done collecting data (or the 10 minutes are up), the data is stored in a String, which is later uploaded to the SD Card as a .csv file.  The problem though is that it takes *forever* for the data to append to the string, due to the massive amount of garbage collecting (it appears to be approximately 5 collects or so per second!)  The appending starts off fast, but seems to be slowing down as more and more as data is added.

This is the loop that causes the lag:

```
           for( i = 0 ; i < len2 ; i++ ) {
                data += accelX[i] + ", " + accelY[i] + ", " + accelZ[i] + 
                ", " + accelT[i] + ", " + latitu[i] + ", " + 
                longit[i] + ", " + orient[i] + ", " + 
                magneX[i] + ", " + magneY[i] + ", " + magneZ[i] + 
                ", " + millis[i] + "\n";

                partialProg = 100.0 * ( (double)(i+1) / (double)(len2));
                dia.setProgress((int) partialProg);

            }
```

`data` is just a String, and nothing is being `new`ed, so I'm unsure of why GC is being called so often.  My question is: what is the problem here, and/or how can I make this more efficient?

Comment: Why not use some kind of data storage structure (e.g. most sensibly a database)? Once each "round" of data is stored in the database it can be essentially "forgotten" until the end when you compile the CSV.

Comment: Consider using a PrintWriter in combination with a BufferedWriter and writing it directly to the file. If you still want to have the String in memory, I would recommend using a StringWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use StringBuilder to concatenate the data:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( i = 0 ; i < len2 ; i++ ) {
    sb.append(accelX[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(accelY[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(accelZ[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(accelT[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(latitu[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(longit[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(orient[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(magneX[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(magneY[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(magneZ[i]).append(", ");
    sb.append(millis[i]).append("\n");
}
```

StringBuilder is [inherently faster](http://kaioa.com/node/59) for building long strings.

It also avoids allocating so many String objects into the heap; since each += operator is creating a new String object rather than modifying the last one. This in turn leads to a large number of GC calls to clean up all the redundent String objects. See also: http://chaoticjava.com/posts/stringbuilder-vs-string/

As Marcelo points out; you may also find dealing with large amounts of data in memory may become problematic on low-spec Android devices, at which point you should consider appending the contents of your StringBuilder to a temporary file every X number of iterations to keep the footprint low. At the end of the process you can stream the file to whatever the destination is planned to be, or read segments of it back to memory on demand.

Comment: It is not true that each + operator creates a new String object, the very link you posted debunks that. One expression with + operators uses one StringBuilder.

Comment: All the other answers were helpful, but approved this one because of the nice explanation/full code example.  Thank you, this is working.

Comment: U Mad: he is not executing one expression, he is appending to "data" on each loop. But you are right, under single assignment situations the compiler can optimise out the operators with a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a lot of objects. every time you use the `operator+`, you actually create a new object, which is expansive [if you repeat it a lot of times]

You can make it more efficient by using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to it, and create the String when you are done.

for example:

```
sb.append(accelX[i]).append(',').append(accelY[i]).append(',').append(accelZ[i]);
```

[where sb is an instance of StringBuilder]

Answer (score 1):

One improvement you may do is, StringBuffer to construct data, that way you don't you can avoid String construction and concatenation operations. For example:

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
buff.append(accelX[i]).append(...).apend(...)
```

Comment: -1 for still creating a lot of String objects inside the append: `accelX[i]+","+.....` is also creating more String objects

Answer (score 1):

`+` operator on strings actually uses `StringBuilder`, thus you do perform at least two allocations per loop (new `StringBuilder` and then `StringBuilder` creates a string when `.toString()` is called on it to assign the result to `data`).
Best way to tackle this is to create a `StringBuilder` in front of the loop.

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
String sep = ", ";
for( i = 0 ; i < len2 ; i++ ) {
    buf.append(accelX[i]).append(sep).append(accelY[i]).append(sep);
    buf.append(accelZ[i]).append(sep).append(accelT[i]).append(sep);
    buf.append(latitu[i]).append(sep).append(longit[i]).append(sep);
    buf.append(magneX[i]).append(sep).append(magneY[i]).append(sep);
    buf.append(magneZ[i]).append(sep).append(millis[i]).append('\n');
    partialProg = 100.0 * ( (double)(i+1) / (double)(len2));
    dia.setProgress((int) partialProg);
}
```